# how can i use this for every hour? now its working every day 16.30

Tags: android, calendar

I'm creating notification system I need to give notification every hour but now it's only giving one for a day

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` so it will execute every 24h change it with `alarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR`

Comment: after using that i can remove these rows right  
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Comment: so can u tell me how that works im really new to those things. in which time its going to give first notification

Comment: well if you need it to start right now you use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` else you use the calendar that you declared

Answer (score 1):

```
     alarmManager. setRepeating  (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  alarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,   pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can write your own class that extends TimerTask like

```
public class ReminderTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Reminding you of something!"); 
    }
}
```

And then start it like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new ReminderTask(), 0, 3600000); // one hour in millis
```

But admittedly, Oussema Aroua's answer is the way to go in this case…